# Data Massaging using aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is in follow up to my earlier problem. I have a collection called coln, where I store a field called costheads in abbreviations : - mnfc for manufacturing, sls for sales.

My aggregate framework is supposed to read from this collection, and aggregate it along with replacing these abbreviations with their actual words.

See the code below: -

```
    db.coln.aggregate(
    {$match: {"year" : "2010","companyName" :/ABC/}},
    {$unwind:"$hierarchy"},
    {$unwind:"$hierarchy.Details" },
    {
       $group:
        {   "_id": 
            {"companyName": "$companyName", 
            "year": "$year",
            "costHead": "$hierarchy.originalName"},
    "total": { "$sum": "$hierarchy.Details.values" }}
    },
    {$project: {_id:0, "Firm":"$_id.companyName", "Year":"$_id.year",
      "costHead": { $cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$_id.costHead", "Mnfc"] }, then:         "Manufacturing", else: "$_id.costHead" } }, 
      "Total":"$total"
    }},
    {$project: {_id:0, "Firm":"$_id.companyName", "Year":"$_id.year",
      "costHead": { $cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$_id.costHead", "Sls"] }, then:         "Sales", else: "$_id.costHead" } }, 
      "Total":"$total"
    }})
```

The problem with this code is that it returns

> {}
>   {}

However if I remove the 2nd last projection: (see below) -

```
    db.coln.aggregate(
    {$match: {"year" : "2010","companyName" :/ABC/}},
    {$unwind:"$hierarchy"},
    {$unwind:"$hierarchy.Details" },
    {
       $group:
        {   "_id": 
            {"companyName": "$companyName", 
            "year": "$year",
            "costHead": "$hierarchy.originalName"},
    "total": { "$sum": "$hierarchy.Details.values" }}
    },
    {$project: {_id:0, "Firm":"$_id.companyName", "Year":"$_id.year",
      "costHead": { $cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$_id.costHead", "Mnfc"] }, then:         "Manufacturing", else: "$_id.costHead" } }, 
      "Total":"$total"
    }})
```

I get 1 document being returned - just 1 document.
The projection seems to filter the remaining documents.

However a filter is not what I want. This is a typical ETL scenario where I want abbreviations to be replaced with their full forms before loading it into a target collection. There are at least a few hundred documents that need to be aggregated and converted.

If I apply the projection it filters off the other 50 documents. I would like all these documents to be displayed.

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: could you provide an example document?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure this out. Check out the code piece below: -

```
db.coln.aggregate(
{$match: {"year" : "2010","companyName" :/ABC/}},
{$unwind:"$hierarchy"},
{$unwind:"$hierarchy.Details" },
{
   $group:
    {   "_id": 
            {"companyName": "$companyName", 
            "year": "$year",
            "costHead": "$hierarchy.originalName"},
    "total": { "$sum": "$hierarchy.Details.values" }}
},
{$project: 
    {_id:0, "Firm":"$_id.companyName", "Year":"$_id.year","costPoint": 
    { $cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$_id.costHead", "Mnfc"] }, 
    then: "Manufacturing", else: 
    { $cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$_id.costHead", "sls"]}, then: "Sales", else: 0}}}},"Total":"$total"}})
```

The key was to figure out how to use these conditional statements effectively in Projection. So apparently I need just 5 pipelines for this.